# SSRS add ungrouped column after row-grouped data

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a sales table, witht he number of sales and the value for each store, grouped by the hour.

What I would like to do, ideally without the use of a subreport, is add a pie chart that details the number of sales by store for each hour and embed this into the table. The intention is to hide the store-level breakdown and toggle display on SaleTime. The pie would become visible for each drill-down row.

Screener to show what I mean

[image: Screener]

The pie needs to exist *within* the table for each saletime, something like the below mockup:

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: You can add the chart into a tablix cell in SSRS, the data for the chart will be limited to the scope of the row it displays on. Just drag the chart to the cell in design mode.

Comment: @R.Richards Limited to the row, which is what I'm trying to get round. I need it at the SALETIME group level, not Detail

Comment: I see. Then you may be able to do this by putting the chart in the matrix column right after (just right of) the Sale Time column, rather than at the end. Not pretty.

Comment: another, not pretty answer might be to create a separate tablix containing just your charts and manually align it to the end of the existing tablix.This would mean that the number of stores and value columns would have to be static, so you would have to report zero's for stores with no sales in the time frame.